# After Deleting Shape.. I Cannot Rotate Anymore.. - JavaFX

Tags: list, javafx, rotation, nodes, shapes

I currently have a program where I can add rectangles to the scene. These can be selected, rotated, resized and deleted.     If I select on a rectangle and click rotate it works, if I add another rectangle and click rotate it still works. However, If I 'DELETE' one of the rectangles then I cannot rotate the other one, or any additional added ones anymore.

I have the following fields and two methods:

```
private List<Node> selectedShapes = new ArrayList<>();
private double angle[] = {0};

@FXML
private AnchorPane container2;
```

**Rotation:**

```
public void rotateObject(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
    angle[0] = angle[0] + 45;
    selectedShapes.get(0).setRotate(angle[0]);
}
```

**Deletion**

```
 public void deleteButton(ActionEvent e) {
    deletebutton.setOnAction(a -> container2.getChildren().removeAll(selectedShapes));
    selectedShapes.remove(0);
}
```

I feel I am selecting or deleting the selected shapes in the incorrect way. Could someone guide me as to what the correct way to select the current item would be.   So if I delete one of the rectangles, the other one should still be rotatable.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a Rectangle List, so instead of going through the base class `Node` why not use list of Rectangle/Shape directly :

```
List<Shape> selectedShapes = new ArrayList<>();
```

And for your problem, you use an array `angle[]`, this one can not be extended, and there you call only index 0, i understand (if I'm not mistaken) that this array is to store the angle of each `Rectangle` to solve it uses a List there too:

```
List<Double> angle = new ArrayList<>();
```

And finally to find yourself in your list, uses an int that you increment (at the time of the addition) and decrement (at the time of the deletion) :

```
int Index = 0;
```

**Edit:**
Here's a simple methods that you could follow to organize your project :

```
private List<Rectangle> recs = new ArrayList<>();
private final double width = 50, height = 50;
private final double x = 200, y = 200;


public void add(){

    recs.add(new Rectangle(x, y, width, height));
    /*Properties of your rectangle (fill,shape...)*/

}

public void delete(int deleteIndex){

    /*Here the root is the container of your Rectangles*/
    root.getChildren().remove(recs.get(deleteIndex));
    recs.remove(deleteIndex);

}

public void rotate(int recIndex, double angle){

    recs.get(recIndex).setRotate(recs.get(recIndex).getRotate()+angle);

}
```

Good luck !

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply.   So how would I write this in my rotate/delete method. Thanks

Comment: I just had to use your delete method and that made it work exactly how I wanted to!    Thank you very much Bo!